# Jenkins - Read Only Access

Tags: windows-7, permissions, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins at C:\Jenkins but cannot disable 'Read-only' access to the folder.

This means I cannot create MSTest results files when running tests as Access is denied.

Any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

My path to MSTest was incorrect. A poorly worded error message in my opinion!